# Error AADSTS500011 accessing SharePoint Online site with Azure AD App-Only using Office365-REST-Python-Client

Tags: python, azure, sharepoint-online, office365api

I am trying to connect to a SharePoint Online site with Azure AD App-Only. I am using Office365-REST-Python-Client v2.3.5 (https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client).

I have followed the instructions of the following link to grant access via Azure AD App-Only: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread. API Permission Sites.FullControl.All has been granted to my application via "Application Permissions" in the Microsoft Azure Portal. I have also made sure that admin consent has been granted to the API Permissions.

I am able to successfully access my SharePoint Online root site https://{my_tenant_name}.sharepoint.com and upload files to the document library "Documents" without any problems. But if I try to access another SharePoint Online site, https://{my_tenant_name}.sharepoint.com/sites/test, other than my the root site, I receive the following error:

"AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://{my_tenant_name}.sharepoint.com/sites/test was not found in the tenant named {tenant_guid}. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant."

I have double-checked the SharePoint Online site url, the tenant guid and API permissions including consent by admin but I am not sure what is causing the error.

Below is my code which can reproduce the problem:

```
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

# Access to the SharePoint Online root site works
# site_url = 'https://{my_tenant_name}.sharepoint.com'
# Other than SharePoint Online root site gives AADSTS500011 error
site_url = 'https://{my_tenant_name}.sharepoint.com/sites/test'
app_settings = {
    'tenant': '{my_tenant_name}.onmicrosoft.com',
    'client_id': '<$guid>',
    'thumbprint': "<$base64CertHash>",
    'certificate_path': 'selfsigned_certificate.pem',
}
ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_client_certificate(
    app_settings.get('tenant'),
    app_settings.get('client_id'),
    app_settings.get('thumbprint'),
    app_settings.get('certificate_path')
)
current_web = ctx.web
ctx.load(current_web)
ctx.execute_query()
print("current_web.url: {}".format(current_web.url))
```

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution for this? I'm having exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving the application the following API permissions:

- Files.ReadWrite.All
- Sites.ReadWrite.All

With this access we are able to use the SharePoint features from the Microsoft Graph API. We use the following code to get a token:

```py
import msal

# Get a token
auth = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}'
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id, authority=auth, client_credential=client_secret)
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'])

token = result['access_token']
```

Retrieving a list then looks like this ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)):

```py
import requests
# Define the headers of the request
headers = {'Authorization': "Bearer " + token}

# Make the GET request to the Graph API to get the list
resp = requests.get(
    'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_title}',
    headers=headers
).json()

print(resp)
```

Comment: Isn't Sites.FullControl.All inclusive of Sites.ReadWrite.All?